# Angular Project not working Internet explore

Tags: angular, mean-stack

i have a done a Means Stack web application it is run well in Google chrome,firefox. but it is not run well internet explorer.

In internet explorer it will work after refresh the page.  In my scenario it will automatically done without refresh a page.

for example:all the crud operation are done perfectly in chrome and firefox without refreshing the page. In Internet Explorer it will work after refresh a page.

I don't know why this happend can any one explain me.

Comment: We need much more information about what you are doing, and what behavior you are seeing.

Comment: :@torazaburo:i have updated my question kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code into controller page and add route.js reference into .html page

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to tell you that exact reason using this few informations..

But assuming you are using an angular project created with the angular-cli, then check that `polyfill.ts` and uncomment all stuff..

Maybe it helps!